Matching the start of a sequence in R
I have a series of string in a vector and need to remove the matching starting pattern from the string.  However, I don't know the pattern or how long it is.
stringa <- c("apple_tart", "apple_pie", "apple_fritter")
stringb <- c("baby breath", "baby oil", "baby doll", "baby name")

I would like the results to be.  I need a function or method that will work for both a and b
resultsa  <- c("tart", "pie", "fritter")
resultsb <- c("breath", "oil", "doll", "name")

I know I could do this with str_remove if I knew the pattern or how long the matching pattern was.  Is there a way to do this?  Perhaps first find the starting string pattern to then use str_remove?

What is the pattern?  A word followed by a space or "_"?  Could there be 3 words, what then?

You want last word?

Does the pattern need to be found in every string?

Use Recursion:
remove_common <- function(x){
  a <- unique(substr(x, 1, 1))
  if(length(a) > 1) return(x)
  Recall(substr(x, 2, 100000L))
}
remove_common(stringa)
[1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"
remove_common(stringb)
[1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name"  

Another base R option:
fn <- function(x){
  n <- length(x) - 1
  y <- paste0(x, collapse = " ")
  pat <- regmatches(y, regexec(sprintf("(.*)(?:.*?\\1){%d}\\K", n),y, perl = TRUE))
  sub(unlist(pat)[2], "", x)
}

fn(stringa)
[1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"
fn(stringb)
[1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name"  


Another way:
fn <- function(x){
   f <- function(x, y){
     n <- seq(min(length(x), length(y)))
     e <- cumsum(x[n] != y[n])
     x[e == e[1]]
   }
   v <- paste0(Reduce(f, strsplit(x, "")), collapse = "")
   sub(v, "", x)
 }
fn(stringa)
[1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"
fn(stringb)
[1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name" 


That recursion function is so elegant!  I'm still trying to figure out where the function is changing x. But it clearly works... Thanks for the puzzle.

Figured it out. Thanks again!

You can write a function to find the longest share prefix. For example
common_prefix <- function(x) {
  best <- min(nchar(x))
  while (best > 0) {
    prefix <- substr(x,1, best)
    if (all(prefix==prefix[1])) {
      return(prefix[1])
    } else {
      best <- best - 1
    }
  }
  return("")
}
common_prefix(stringa)
# [1] "apple_"
common_prefix(stringb)
# [1] "baby "

Once you have the common prefix, you can remove it.
remove_common_prefix <- function(x) {
  substring(x, nchar(common_prefix(x))+1)
}

remove_common_prefix(stringa)
# [1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"
remove_common_prefix(stringb)
# [1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name"  

And to reduce the number of comparisons, you could try skipping around. A possible refactor might look like this
common_prefix <- function(x) {
  if (length(x)<2) return(x)
  best <- min(nchar(x))
  prefix <- x
  while (best > 0) {
    prefix <- unique(substr(prefix, 1, best))
    if (all(prefix==prefix[1]) || length(prefix)<2) {
      return(prefix[1])
    } else {
      chars <- strsplit(prefix[1:2],"")
      best <- which(chars[[1]] != chars[[2]])[1]-1
    }
  }
  return("")
}

I don't know exactly how many values you have or how long they are, but you could test this as an alternative.

You can try repeat or while, for example
f <- function(s) {
  k <- 1
  repeat {
    if (length(unique(substr(s, 1, k))) > 1) {
      return(substr(s, k, nchar(s)))
    }
    k <- k + 1
  }
}

such that
> f(stringa)
[1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"

> f(stringb)
[1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name"


Is not this exactly what my recursion looks like?

@Onyambu aha, didn't see your solution when I posted mine. Now I updated it with repeat

Simplified str_split() (i.e. to char matrix), count unique chars in columns and pass those to rle to extract common start pattern length (if there is one). Slight str_sub() abuse for string replacement.
library(stringr)

stringa <- c("apple_tart", "apple_pie", "apple_fritter")
stringb <- c("baby breath", "baby oil", "baby doll", "baby name")
# no common start pattern:
stringc <- c("X baby breath", "baby oil", "baby doll", "baby name")

remove_start_match <- function(strings){
  # split all strings, results in matrix, apply unique over columns,
  # get unique lenghts (1: charcter match at that position), 
  # get run lenghts; if first run value is 1, 
  # first length is the legth of the starting match
  r <- 
    str_split(strings, "", simplify = TRUE) |>
    apply(2, \(x) unique(x)) |>
    lengths() |>
    rle()
  # first run length if first value is 1, otherwise 0
  start_match_len <- (r$values[1] == 1) * r$lengths[1] 
  # if end = 0, str_sub will not replace 
  str_sub(strings, start = 1, end = start_match_len) <- ""
  strings
}

remove_start_match(stringa)
#> [1] "tart"    "pie"     "fritter"
remove_start_match(stringb)
#> [1] "breath" "oil"    "doll"   "name"
remove_start_match(stringc)
#> [1] "X baby breath" "baby oil"      "baby doll"     "baby name"

Step-by-step:
(a <- str_split(stringa, "", simplify = TRUE))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#> [1,] "a"  "p"  "p"  "l"  "e"  "_"  "t"  "a"  "r"  "t"   ""    ""    ""   
#> [2,] "a"  "p"  "p"  "l"  "e"  "_"  "p"  "i"  "e"  ""    ""    ""    ""   
#> [3,] "a"  "p"  "p"  "l"  "e"  "_"  "f"  "r"  "i"  "t"   "t"   "e"   "r"
 b <- apply(a, 2, unique) |> dplyr::glimpse()
#> List of 13
#>  $ : chr "a"
#>  $ : chr "p"
#>  $ : chr "p"
#>  $ : chr "l"
#>  $ : chr "e"
#>  $ : chr "_"
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "t" "p" "f"
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "a" "i" "r"
#>  $ : chr [1:3] "r" "e" "i"
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "t" ""
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "" "t"
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "" "e"
#>  $ : chr [1:2] "" "r"
(d <- lengths(b))
#>  [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 3 3 3 2 2 2 2
(r <- rle(d))
#> Run Length Encoding
#>   lengths: int [1:3] 6 3 4
#>   values : int [1:3] 1 3 2

Created on 2024-06-08 with reprex v2.1.0

If the patterns are always at the start and always the same you can find the common prefix like so:
library(stringr)
stringa <- c("apple_tart", "apple_pie", "apple_fritter")

find_prefix <- function(str1,str2) {
  common_prefix <- ""
  for (i in 1:min(nchar(str1), nchar(str2))) {
    if (substr(str1, 1, i) == substr(str2, 1, i)) {
      common_prefix <- paste0(common_prefix, substr(str1, i, i))
    } else {
      break
    }
  }
  return (common_prefix)
}

remove_prefix <- function(str,pre){
  return (str_remove(str,pre))
}

pre <- find_prefix(stringa[1],stringa[2])

result <- sapply(stringa,remove_prefix,pre=pre)


An approach that only removes the starting words that are also duplicated within the vector.
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

remove_start <- function(x){
  tibble(vec = x) %>% 
    mutate(rmv = 
      purrr::map_vec(vec, ~ paste0(unlist(strsplit(.x, "[ _]"))[1], "[ _]*")),
           dup = duplicated(rmv) | duplicated(rmv, fromLast=T)) %>%
    reframe(if_else(dup, str_remove_all(vec, rmv), vec)) %>%
    unlist(use.names=F)}

applied
stringa
[1] "apple_tart"    "apple_pie"     "apple_fritter" "peach_tree"   

remove_start(stringa)
[1] "tart"       "pie"        "fritter"    "peach_tree"

stringb
[1] "baby breath"  "baby oil"     "no_baby name" "baby doll"    "baby name"

remove_start(stringb)
[1] "breath"       "oil"          "no_baby name" "doll"         "name"

Data
stringa <- c("apple_tart", "apple_pie", "apple_fritter", "peach_tree")
stringb <- c("baby breath", "baby oil", "no_baby name", "baby doll", "baby name")

